# Tomcat : SSL : Webservices : Client + Server on the same Tomcat Instance

Tags: web-services, tomcat, ssl

We have 2 applications on one Tomcat server. Say Application A and B. A uses web services that B offers for data processing.

Do we still need to set up a TrustStore or add the public key to the cacerts available on the JVM tomcat is using?

Comment: There is no need to use SSL on localhost. Is application B exposed to other clients than application A ?

Comment: Yes it would be exposed to other clients as well... We will be sharing out Public Keys with them...

Comment: When you say no need to use on localhost, would I need it if I use a different domain name for the URL??

Comment: If your application B is accessed by remote computers, and if you have to use a login/password or send private data, then it is necessary to use SSL for security reasons. If application B is only accessed by application A and both are running on the same computer, encrypting data is only a waste of time.

Comment: I agree with you, but it's a situation I'm in myself!!

Comment: OK. If you are requesting an SSL site, you always need to accept its certificate (by adding to the truststore, or by coding an X509 implementation). So the answer : yes, add it to the truststore.